# Combination where order matters and you must use all the possible variables

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have 26 locations and 3 workers. I need to assign one and only one worker to each location. Each worker must be assigned to at least one location. How many possible combinations of assignments would I have? I have tried lots of different ideas and mapped out just 3 locations and 2 workers, just 3 locations and 3 workers (this would be just 3! or 6), just 4 locations and 3 workers (I think this is 27, but can't express why that is the case in a formula) and just 5 locations and 3 workers which I believe is 138 different assignments. I have spent considerable time on this, but thought I'd ask for help. Please let me know if you have any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle:

The number of ways we can map $3$ workers to $n$ locations, regardless of whether they all have at least one location or not, is $3^n$.

From these, we can see that $3\cdot2^n$ have used only $2$ workers.

From these, we can see that only $1$ worker has been used $6$ times, so $3\cdot2^n$ will remove an excess of $3$ possibilities.

So a formula is:

$$3^n-3\cdot2^n+3$$

which is [$OEIS:A001117$](https://oeis.org/A001117); number of surjections from an $n$-element set onto a $3$-element set.

I think the general formula for $k$ workers is:

$$(-1)^kk+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (-1)^i\frac{k!}{(k-i)!}(k-i)^n$$

Comment: It may be worth alluding to the general formula for an arbitrary number of workers as well.  This is as I mentioned in my initial comment rather convenient to do using stirling numbers.

Comment: @JMoravitz; bit of a guess this one!

Comment: $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k\end{smallmatrix}\right\}k!$ where $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$ is the [stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  Expressed without stirling numbers, it would be $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k(-1)^{k-i}\binom{k}{i}i^n$.  The explanation being, we first partition the set of worksites into $k$ non-empty subsets (*which is precisely what stirling numbers of second kind counts*) and then choose how to label the subsets.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry  Thanks for the explanation. I'm looking at this so I can better understand it.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I have verified this formula that you gave for 3 workers and it definitely works.  Plus it pointed out that I had several work assignments that I had overlooked when I did this by hand. Super solution! Thank you